# Down is escaping my jacket, especially over a wool sweater

Tags: jackets, down

I recently bought a down jacket and noticed that some down is leaking, especially if I am wearing a wool sweater underneath.

Everytime I wear my jacket with my (dark, which makes the down very visible) wool sweater, I notice anywhere between 20 and 50 filaments stuck on my sweater. I assume this is because of static.

The jacket is not 1 month old yet. Is it normal that I still notice some leakage from now and then (even when not wearing wool underneath)? Do people not usually wear wool with down jackets?

Comment: Sounds similar to when you get a new jumper and it leaves excess material on your shirt underneath?

Answer (score 3):

Down will inevitably pierce through thin fabrics (an thicker ones too, just less frequently). It's in the nature of quills to do so and even if very fine, there are quills nonetheless. The lighter the denier of the fabric or the looser it's woven, the easier the down will get through.

Short of having a garment that is lined with something that slows this process, your only option is to prevent the down from going all the way through when you notice it by plucking it back inside through the jacket.

Maybe the wool shirt is attracting the down when it's already out, but it shouldn't actually be causing more down to go through.